# .NET Core 5.0 - IServiceCollection.Configure and ILogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-5

I have a library that registers its services:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddViewStringRenderer(this IServiceCollection services, string contentRootPath, ILogger logger)
{
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => { options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander(contentRootPath, logger)); });
    services.AddTransient<IRazorViewToStringRenderer, RazorViewToStringRenderer>();
    ...
    return services;
}
```

and, as you may see, I need a logger for `services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(...)`, so it is a param to this extension method.

But since the method is used in `Startup.ConfigureServices()` we don't have a way to instanciate `ILogger` there in .NET 5. How would it be possible to pass the logger to `services.Configure()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, big thanks to David Fowler for pointing out this pattern - [Resolving services when using IOptions](https://github.com/davidfowl/DotNetCodingPatterns/blob/main/1.md#resolving-services-when-using-ioptionst).

Here's the result:

```
public class RazorViewEngineConfigureOptions : IConfigureOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>
{
    private readonly ILogger<ViewLocationExpander> _logger;
    private readonly string _contentRootPath;

    public RazorViewEngineConfigureOptions(IHostEnvironment env, ILogger<ViewLocationExpander> logger)
    {
        _contentRootPath = env.ContentRootPath;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Configure(RazorViewEngineOptions options)
    {
       options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander(_contentRootPath, _logger));
    }
}

public static class RegisterServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddEmailerService(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>, RazorViewEngineConfigureOptions>();
        services.AddTransient<IRazorViewToStringRenderer, RazorViewToStringRenderer>();

        ...
        return services;
    }
}
```